# Photoelectric effect graph between photoelectric current and collector plate potential

Tags: photoelectric-effect

[image]

I am not able to understand the significance of this graph.
Can anyone help me??

Comment: What did you not understand? Please tell a specific thing.

Comment: @user7186002...it explains that , the more potential you apply within the cathode and anode , the more photo electric current will flow . However,for a specific set of cathode-anode , the stopping potential is same...

Comment: Please don't cut and paste on the internet without crediting the author. It's rude.

Comment: Significance in relation to what?

Answer (score 3):

You must see the curves   in the light of photoelectric  equation;

Photo electron Kinetic Energy (max) =  h. frequency  - W (work function)

From above  equation, it is clear that the number of photons incident should have  no effect on the energy of the photoelectrons.

However, If  the intensity of light is changed (increased or decreased) the number of photoelectrons that are released gets affected .

As each photon is capable of releasing only one electron, then if there are more photons, then there is release of more electrons.

So for three  intensities the photo current curve takes different paths depending upon the available electrons.

However as the photo active plate is of same material having unique  work function  the stopping potential  remains same  as defined by the guiding equation.